# Can associative entities be inherited?

Tags: database, relationship, entity-relationship

Suppose in the ER diagram there is an associative entity named *makes call* which connects the entities *External entity* and *Internal entity*. Is it possible for the associative entity to be inherited as shown in the following picture?[image: See picture]

Comment: are this call will be presented as a different data or will get the same data ?

Comment: @Faesal, I want scheduled call & realtime call to have the same attributes as makes call.